# Поменять местами min и max в списке

Tags: python

Есть задание:
На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая различные натуральные числа.
Из данной строки формируется список чисел.
Напишите программу, которая меняет местами минимальный и максимальный элемент этого списка.

```
numbers = 3 4 5 2 1
```

Не могу понять, почему выдаёт ошибку:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Ведь я перевёл весь список в `int`.
Или список сместился?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```py
numbers = input().split()
s2 = []
for c in numbers:
    s2.append(int(c))
s_max= max(s2)
s_min = min(s2)
s_max.index = s2.index(s_max)
s_min.index = s2.index(s_min)
s2[s_max.index], s2[s_min.index] = s2[s_min.index], s2[s_max.index]
print(*s2)
```

Comment: я нашёл косяк  переменную  s_max.index назвал не правильно . вот так глаз за мылился

Comment: У чисел нет и никогда не было атрибута index

Answer (score 1):

Практически верно, только немного иначе.Как было уже сказано ранее, у чисел нет метода `.index`

Можно просто создать новую переменную. Выглядит итог примерно так:

```py
numbers = input().split()
s2 = []
for c in numbers:
    s2.append(int(c))
s_max = max(s2)
s_min = min(s2)
s_max_index = s2.index(s_max)
s_min_index = s2.index(s_min)
s2[s_max_index], s2[s_min_index] = s2[s_min_index], s2[s_max_index]
print(*s2)
```

Если чуток сократить программу, то можно написать так:

```py
nums = list(map(int,input("Введите числа:\t ").split()))
ind_max = nums.index(max(nums))
ind_min = nums.index(min(nums))
nums[ind_max], nums[ind_min] = nums[ind_min], nums[ind_max]
print("Результат:\t", *nums)
```